# Program to count distance between coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this program I parse json data which contains key-'id' and value-'coord' to python dictionary. I am new in python, so sorry that code is not pythonic-way). My problem is in line z = myDict.get(n). It returns me always the same value, but I'd like to have it change by 1 next key every 49 iterations(because I do have 49 coordinates) Here is my json looks like:

```
 {"status" : "200", 
    "result" : [{"id":10001,"coord":"45.781231 78.784321"},{"id":10002,"coord":"45.481684 78.743410},{"id":10003,"coord":"45.411934 78.543113}, etc the same 50 dicts.
```

Would be very thankful if you help me.

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
import requests 
import itertools 


def data():
    response = requests.get('')
    json_data = response.json()
    global myDict
    myDict = {}
    for each in json_data['result']:
    myDict.update ({each['id']: (each['coord'])})


    myDict[10252] = '43.238454 76.949185'
    myDict = {str(k):(v) for k,v in myDict.items()}
    keys, values = zip(*myDict.items())
    for v in itertools.product(*values):
        experiment = dict(zip(keys, v))    
        for key,value in experiment.items():
        x = myDict[key]
        for n,m in experiment.items():
            z = myDict.get(n)
        var1,var2 = x.split()
        var3,var4 = z.split()                                                                                                   
        R = 6373.0 
        lat1 = radians(float(var1)),radians(float(var2))
        lat2 = radians(float(var3)),radians(float(var4))
        dlon = lat2[1]-lat1[1]
        dlat = lat2[0]-lat1[0]
        a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1[0]) * cos(lat2[0]) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        distance = int((R * c)*1000)
        print ("Result:", distance)
        print(x,z)
 g = data()
 print(g)
```

My given output is:
As you can see numbers are equal every 49 iterations. It compares every "id" value with only "id":10001. And I want it to compare with "id": 10002, 10003, 10004 etc..

```
Result: 0
Result: 55
Result: 1987
Result: 1345
Result: 3290
Result: 4380
Result: 2058
Result: 4715
Result: 910
Result: 2501
Result: 1176
Result: 3958
Result: 3622
Result: 534
Result: 1176
Result: 922
Result: 2154
Result: 3440
Result: 2749
Result: 1530
Result: 2139
Result: 919
Result: 1264
Result: 3331
Result: 1559
Result: 3542
Result: 3752
Result: 4684
Result: 3262
Result: 5653
Result: 6239
Result: 5827
Result: 6245
Result: 1444
Result: 754
Result: 1755
Result: 453
Result: 5459
Result: 7287
Result: 1642
Result: 4506
Result: 4266
Result: 493
Result: 1029
Result: 4944
Result: 4744
Result: 5206
Result: 2683
Result: 0
Result: 55
Result: 1987
Result: 1345
Result: 3290
Result: 4380
Result: 2058
Result: 4715
Result: 910
Result: 2501
Result: 1176
Result: 3958
Result: 3622
Result: 534
Result: 1176
Result: 922
Result: 2154
Result: 3440
Result: 2749
Result: 1530
Result: 2139
Result: 919
Result: 1264
Result: 3331
Result: 1559
Result: 3542
Result: 3752
Result: 4684
Result: 3262
Result: 5653
Result: 6239
Result: 5827
Result: 6245
Result: 1444
Result: 754
Result: 1755
Result: 453
Result: 5459
Result: 7287
Result: 1642
Result: 4506
Result: 4266
Result: 493
Result: 1029
Result: 4944
Result: 4744
Result: 5206
Result: 2683
Result: 0
Result: 55
Result: 1987
Result: 1345
Result: 3290
Result: 4380
Result: 2058
Result: 4715
Result: 910
Result: 2501
Result: 1176
Result: 3958
Result: 3622
Result: 534
Result: 1176
Result: 922
Result: 2154
Result: 3440
Result: 2749
Result: 1530
Result: 2139
Result: 919
Result: 1264
Result: 3331
Result: 1559
Result: 3542
Result: 3752
Result: 4684
Result: 3262
Result: 5653
Result: 6239
Result: 5827
Result: 6245
Result: 1444
Result: 754
Result: 1755
Result: 453
Result: 5459
Result: 7287
Result: 1642
Result: 4506
Result: 4266
Result: 493
Result: 1029
Result: 4944
Result: 4744
Result: 5206
Result: 2683
```

Comment: Did you try to print `n` so that you can see the value changes?

Comment: your program is unnecessarily complicated. why you build a `dict` and then use it as a `list`?

Comment: and place provide [mCve] example.

Comment: Oh I tried to print and found that the problem is in x = myDict[key]

Comment: Because I have to change string to float.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should edit your second for loop and re-align to compare every id with every other id.

```
for v in itertools.product(*values):
        experiment = dict(zip(keys, v))    
        for key,value in experiment.items():
         x = myDict[key]
         z = myDict.get(key)
         var1,var2 = x.split()
         var3,var4 = z.split()                                                                                                   
         R = 6373.0 
         lat1 = radians(float(var1)),radians(float(var2))
         lat2 = radians(float(var3)),radians(float(var4))
         dlon = lat2[1]-lat1[1]
         dlat = lat2[0]-lat1[0]
         a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1[0]) * cos(lat2[0]) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
         c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
         distance = int((R * c)*1000)
         print ("Result:", distance)
         print(x,z)
```

You can use vincenty from geopy for calculating distance.

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
dist = vincenty(p1, p2)
```

if you want the result in kilometers:

```
dist = vincenty(p1, p2).kilometers
```

p1 and p2 should be tuples.

Comment: Oh no, the problem is not in this.

Comment: I can edit my answer to be more helpful if you provide expected output and given output.